# struct inode in system has number of blocks & block numbers but no corresponding data offset byte in storage device.HowFilesystem evenWorks without it

Tags: c, filesystems, storage, disk, inode

I like to know how data is stored in storage. So what I know about a simple file system organizational struct that contains meta data about a file called inode is that it has two member fields

struct inode {
blkcnt_t        i_blocks;
...
loff_t          i_size;
}

I am assuming that i_blocks is storing block numbers. but how block numbers are numbered? its of type u64

so the question is if this field contains all the block [numbers] then how they are stored u64 means 64 bit and if I represent each 4 bit relate to block numbers then there are 16 blocks per inode. so for example if i_blocks field is `0b1111 1110....` so 1111 is block number 15 and 1110 is block number 14 and so on. so I like to know if number of bits to represent a block number is 4 bit then there can be only 15 blocks in inode so this way I have block numbers and number of blocks but I still could not field the third field which is >>> what is the base address of data block so for example if inode number is 1111 that correspond to `some.txt` text file with data hello world then where is the offset of `hello world` data in storage device. This data offset field array of corresponding inode numbers I could not find. Can any one please direct me to the answer in where I can find the data offset byte in storage medium and it has to be in inode struct?

Comment: Where did you find this structure? In which book or on what site? Doesn't the book or site contain any documentation about the structure or its members?

Comment: As for the `i_blocks` member, the name of the type `blkcnt_t` should give a hint what `i_blocks` might be: It's a *count* of the number of blocks the file occupies.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude its linux kernel source containing inode struct in linnux/fs.h

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `As for the i_blocks member, the name of the type blkcnt_t should give a hint what i_blocks might be: It's a count of the number of blocks the file occupies.` so why I only need to care about number of blocks (I am assuming u mean data  blocks)  why data offset does not matter in inode struct, without it how I will make file system work

Comment: For which Linux version? Version 5.10 does not have that structure, at least not in that file.

Comment: You might also want to invest in some text-books about operating systems and file systems. How old-style inode-based filsystems work is well-documented in both books and all over the Internet. Usually there's an array of direct and indirect block pointers that list all the blocks used by the file, often using a "standard" zero-based indexing scheme (where block 0 is the first block on the disk, usually the boot block).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `Usually there's an array of direct and indirect block pointers that list all the blocks used by the file, often using a "standard" zero-based indexing scheme (where block 0 is the first block on the disk, usually the boot block).` can u please tell what that direct and indirect pointer is of type? Which data type? I know they should be char * type or void * to point to storage area but in inode struct does not matter which linux version there is no char or void pointer type u can check it?

Comment: Neither there is any array in inode struct that I can relate to direct and indirect pointers in inode struct

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Btw u can check kernel 5.15 I could not find any direct and indirect pointer pointing to some data blocks in inode struct. And there is inode struct in fs.h in kernel 5.15

Comment: I see the structure now, and it's an internal in-memory structure used by the VFS (Virtual File System) layer. It's not how inodes actually looks on the disk. If you want to know the on-disk layout of inode-type filesystems you really should get some books on operating systems and how they work. Or at the very least find some filesystem tutorials on the Internet.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes I know what VFS is and all file systems inherit the VFS inode struct in their code base. If u want u ignore the Kernel vfs inode then see the implementation of actual ext2 file system and yes u will sure find the same inode in the code of ext2. VfS is just template that every filesystem has to follow on Linux. Please give me the simple explanation if u can about the data offset field in inode struct or let someone else

Comment: `i_blocks` is the number of blocks the file occupies. `i_size` is the size in bytes. There's no "offset" or list of blocks in those two members.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude please confirm i_size is the size of all blocks space so I can assume each block is 1024 bytes so for example if i_size is 3072 bytes then there are three blocks each size 1024 bytes. Can u please confirm this?

Comment: Assuming a block-size of 1KiB, and a file-size of 72 bytes. Then `i_size == 72` and `i_blocks == 1` (because all those 72 bytes will fit in a single data block). If the size of the file is instead 1254 bytes, then `i_size == 1254` while `i_blocks == 2` (because two data-blocks is needed to store all the data).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so last question can I store all the inodes structs before all the data blocks. So for example if all I have is only 3 inodes representing three text files on entire new block device then 3 inodes stored in the beginning of my block device and then data blocks contains text files data stored afterwards?

Comment: or can inode(s) offset address be found from group descriptor?

Comment: @user786 please do some reading (on UFS, which is the simplest) Blocks[] ={1 superblock + X inode blocks + Y data blocks} An Inode contains some aggregates {size,count,type,...)}+ an array of block numbers; the last of these can refer to (double) indirect blocks.

Comment: @wildplasser what do u mean by `X inode blcks` is this like if I have three regular text files then there are three inode blocks ? whats the size of inode block, I am assuming whatever the size of struct inode is that what inode block size will be so if there are three files there three inodes. Can u please clearify.

Comment: @user786 Files dont exist at this level. A disk (or disk partition) is viewed as an array of blocks[] = { superblock[1] ,  inodeblocks[xxx] , datablocks[yyy]  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short sketch for finding inode number **ii**:

- find the inode **block** where **ii** lives: `ii/InodesPerBlock`; use this as an index into the inodeblocks.
- find the **index** into this block : `ii%InodesPerBlock`
- treat (*cast*) this location as an Inode, and use the first entry in the blocks[] array as the **number** of the first data block.

For finding a **file**, this operation must be precededed by a similar operation for finding the **directory** entry and finding the file's **inodeNumber**

NOTE: there are a lot of *manifest* constants, these can all be found in the **superblock**

- Block **size**
- filesystem **Type**
- size of a blockNumber
- number of Inode Blocks (or: number of Inodes)
- size of an **inode** (or: InodesPerBlock)
- Number of Data Blocks
- Location of the inode containing the **root Directory**
- Location of the **freelist** containing the unused block numbers
- State/backup/...
- et cetera ...

NOTE2: this is a *simplified* scheme. Modern file systems may contain additional structures for efficiency or redundancy. Also: a filesystem may combine more than one **physical** block into one **logical** block (e.g. 8*512 -->> 4096)

NOTE3: the **superblock** is located at **blocknumber=0** (at least in UFS) That means that `0` can be used as sentinel value for **blocknumbers** referring to *actual* (non-root) blocks. So, the blocknumber arrays inside the **inode**s can be initialized to all-zeros.

NOTE4: these structures all reside on disk. The kernel may maintain (it will!) additional, similar structures in memory. These structures will refer to both themselves (using pointers, or offsets, or indices) or they will refer to disk blocks (numbers).

Comment: So what is the size of inodesPerBlock == number of inodes in that block <===what is the size of that block that contains all the inodesPer block. Many inodes in a block

Comment: Given the size of a block, the size of an anode can be computed using the number of inodes per block, or vice versa. And: size of a block is a **fixed** constant.

Comment: so if for example I have 32 inodes where the data blocks be stored? is it first inode +32==data blocks offset?

Comment: Don't confuse blocks and block **numbers**.

Comment: Ok also last question if I have ext2 formatted file system image then how to store file path. I only have inode object and block group descriptor object with bg_members and super block object. That's what I am working on for last few days. Trying to understand. So for example if user ran a cp command I need to copy file path somewhere in the image file. Can u tell me this.

Comment: Ext2 is more complicated. Very much more complicated. Remember: these are only the basics.